# ASP.NET ASHX Handler for testing preloaders (with an image and delay) not delaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image-preloader

I'm working on my personal website and I have a gallery in which I need to implement a preloader. In order to test, I decided to make my own .ashx handler to test image loading (with a simple Thread.Sleep() for simulating network delay) but Firefox does not display them one by one as they finish loading, but all at once. It's weird since where the images are to be shown there are no tables, only divs, so they should show up on-the-fly.

In random cases though, it shows, let's say, 3, and then the other 2 (let's assume I have 5 images) show up. I'd like them to load in random intervals, but I dunno what could be wrong in my code.

Here's my .ashx code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="GetImg" %>
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;

public class GetImg : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new System.Random((int)System.DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(5) * 1000);
        ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        ctx.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/test.jpg")));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help you guys can provide :)

Comment: When you put two "links" to your ashx handler into your website, it is highly likely that they will be called parallel, not one after the other. Hence, the images appear at once. This depends on the browser and how many concurrent connections to the server it is allowed to make.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, thanks for explaining it :D I managed to do a workaround by locking the server instead using Context.Application as shown by @Emanuele Greco :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browsers starts downloading images in parallel; there's no reason to wait for first image to ask for the second one!

Your webserver, too, starts a session (and a thread) for each request. So, both sessions start in the same second, and wait 5*1000 together... and send response at the same moment.

You can think some kind of trick:
   - realize a queue in the server (using `Context.Application` to make Threads communicate each other), so that images can be served in sequence
   - use a random number instead of `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` to have random delay

but the actual behaviour is emulating a real situation of many images served by a server with same delay time.

Comment: Thanks Emanuele, I thought that the Thread.Sleep was locking the server in the .ashx handler, but as Alexander and you explained, the server and browser are doing the requests in parallel. I managed to use your suggestion of Context.Application to lock the server using HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock(); and Unlock(); and put my Thread.Sleep in-between. I need to make the delays a bit more random, but for testing my preloader it's more than enough. Thanks!